# jQuery.post callback not executing

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, post, callback

When I make a call with jQuery.post, the callback is not being executed, but only if the call is made in a js file loaded into the webpage. If I copy and paste the same call into the javascript console of the browser, the callback get's executed. I know that the function is being called, because if I replace the call to jQuery.post with a simple alert(), it shows up. I've made sure the post request is completing (data is inserted into db on server side). I've also made sure that it is returning with a 200 code.

Also, this function is being called on demand when I click a button, so the DOM should be fully loaded by then.

Why would this be executed properly from the console, but not from a js file?

Comment: Where's the code? :) **Always** post the relevant code.

Comment: Wild guess: XSS security restrictions?

Comment: Try to check whether you are refering the url path correctly or not. I think there will be an error. Use `$.ajax` and see if it invokes the error calback.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem ended up being that I wasn't returning false from the onclick callback, and so the page was refreshing every time I submitted the form. The refresh happened so fast that I didn't notice. If I moved the submit button out of the form, or returned false from the onclick callback, the expected behaviour occurred.